# System.OutOfMemoryException and complication with Using StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stringbuilder

The following code give me System.OutOfMemoryException and i tried to change it by using StringBuilder in my code but i couldn't succeed in using it.

anyone can tell me what is the best approach to use StringBuilder instead of many concatenations between strings in my code?

```
Dim sReport As String = ""
For i As Integer = 1 To oPuntInterpretar.Dies.Count

    ' DGARCIA: Per MeteoPlay3 no ens interessa que hi hagi diferència en l'hora local UTC, 
    '          ja que cada previsió s'ofereix des del mateir punt evaluat.
    oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC = 0

    If (oConfiguracio.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
        ' Dades del report...
        sReport = "ID_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & oPuntInterpretar.IPuntGeografic & vbCrLf & _
                  "LATITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Latitud, 2) & vbCrLf & _
                  "LONGITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Longitud, 2) & vbCrLf & _
                  "ALCADA_PUNTGEOGRAFIC (metres);" & oPuntInterpretar.Alçada & vbCrLf & _
                  "TIPUS_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & IIf(oPuntInterpretar.Tipus = clsPuntGeografic.TipusPunt.Poblacio, "POBLACIO", "MUNTANYA") & vbCrLf & _
                  "DIF_HORALOCAL_UTC;" & oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC & vbCrLf & _
                  "DATA_MODEL;" & dtDataElaboracio.ToString & vbCrLf & _
                  "DATA_VALIDESA;" & oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).DataValidesa.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End If

    ' a + a + de les hores calculem TMax i TMin
    oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMin(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport)
    sReport &= vbCrLf
    oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMax(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport)
    sReport &= vbCrLf

    ' Ara mirem si tenim hores per aquest dia...
    For j As Integer = 1 To oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).Hores.count

        With oPuntInterpretar

            ' VentVel (km/hora -> passar a Beaufort!)
            ' VentDir (ºC -> passar a CodiVent)
            ' Després caldrà juntar els dos valors a CodiVent per insertar en base de dades!

            .CalculaVentDir(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

            .CalculaVentVel(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

            If (.Dies(i).Hores(j).VentVel <> clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE) And (.Dies(i).Hores(j).VentDir <> clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE) Then
                .Dies(i).Hores(j).CodiVent = CalculaDirTaula(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j).VentDir) & GrauBeaufort(.Dies(i).Hores(j).VentVel, oConfiguracio.TaulaGrauBeaufort)
                sReport &= vbCrLf
            Else
                .Dies(i).Hores(j).CodiVent = ""
            End If

            .CalculaTempSuperficie(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

            If (j = 1) Then
                .CalculaPluja(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .Dies(i).Hores(j).tipusHora, .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
                sReport &= vbCrLf
            Else
                .CalculaPluja(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .Dies(i).Hores(j - 1).tipusHora + 1, .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
                sReport &= vbCrLf
            End If

            .CalculaPressio(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

            .CalculaNuvolositat(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport, False)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

            .CalculaSimbol(oConfiguracio, .Dies(i).Hores(j), .VariablesPG, .DifHoraLocalUTC, .Alçada, i - 1, moDB, iHoresRestar, sReport, False, True)
            sReport &= vbCrLf

        End With
```

I tried to use it like this but it seems it doesn't work. i can guess it is something about `&=`operator or something wrong in appending.

The code after change:

```
Dim sReport As new StringBuilder

    Try

        iHoresRestar = dtDataElaboracio.Hour

        ' Per cada dia, calculem els valors de les tres franges i totes les hores...
        For i As Integer = 1 To oPuntInterpretar.Dies.Count

            ' DGARCIA: Per MeteoPlay3 no ens interessa que hi hagi diferència en l'hora local UTC, 
            '          ja que cada previsió s'ofereix des del mateir punt evaluat.
            oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC = 0

            If (oConfiguracio.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
                ' Dades del report...
                sReport.Append("ID_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & oPuntInterpretar.IPuntGeografic & vbCrLf & _
                          "LATITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Latitud, 2) & vbCrLf & _
                          "LONGITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Longitud, 2) & vbCrLf & _
                          "ALCADA_PUNTGEOGRAFIC (metres);" & oPuntInterpretar.Alçada & vbCrLf & _
                          "TIPUS_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;" & IIf(oPuntInterpretar.Tipus = clsPuntGeografic.TipusPunt.Poblacio, "POBLACIO", "MUNTANYA") & vbCrLf & _
                          "DIF_HORALOCAL_UTC;" & oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC & vbCrLf & _
                          "DATA_MODEL;" & dtDataElaboracio.ToString & vbCrLf & _
                          "DATA_VALIDESA;" & oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).DataValidesa.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            End If

            ' a + a + de les hores calculem TMax i TMin
            oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMin(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport.ToString)
            sReport.AppendLine()
            oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMax(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport.ToString)
            sReport.AppendLine()
```

**UPDATE ------------------------**

This is one of the functions which pass the sReport to it:

```
Public Function CalculaVentDir(ByVal config As clsConfiguracio, _
                               ByRef unaHora As clsHora, _
                               ByVal colVars As clsVariables, _
                               ByVal DifHoraLocalUTC As Integer, _
                               ByVal Alçada As Double, _
                               ByVal difDies As Integer, _
                               ByVal horaModel As Integer, _
                               ByRef strReport As String, _
                      Optional ByVal UtilitzemDifHoraLocalUTC As Boolean = True _
                              ) As Boolean

    Dim U, V As Double
    Dim angle As Double
    Dim horaIni, posU, posV As Integer
    Dim ventDir As Double
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTmp(7) As String

    Try

        If (colVars.CercaVariable(New clsVariable(33, 105, 10), posU) = True) And _
           (colVars.CercaVariable(New clsVariable(34, 105, 10), posV) = True) _
        Then

            If (UtilitzemDifHoraLocalUTC = True) Then
                horaIni = unaHora.tipusHora - DifHoraLocalUTC + difDies * 24 - horaModel
            Else
                horaIni = unaHora.tipusHora + difDies * 24 - horaModel
            End If

            strTmp(0) = "DIRECCIO DEL VENT"
            strTmp(1) = "Hora local"
            strTmp(2) = "Hora UTC"
            strTmp(3) = "Component U"
            strTmp(4) = "Component V"
            strTmp(5) = "Angle exacte"
            strTmp(6) = "Angle segons quadrant"
            strTmp(7) = "Angle aproximat"

            strMsg = "|Hora=" & unaHora.tipusHora & "|difDies=" & difDies & "|difHoraLocalUTC=" & DifHoraLocalUTC & "|horaModel=" & horaModel & "|horaIni=" & horaIni
            strTmp(1) &= ";" & unaHora.tipusHora
            strTmp(2) &= ";" & horaIni

            If (horaIni < 0) Then
                If (config.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
                    RaiseEvent GetWarning("MESSAGE=No hem calculat la VentDir perquè la hora està fora dels marges" & strMsg & "|FUNCIO=CalculaVentDir_Hora", Me)
                End If
                unaHora.VentDir = clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE
                CalculaVentDir = False
            End If

            U = colVars.Valors(posU - 1, horaIni)
            V = colVars.Valors(posV - 1, horaIni)

            strTmp(3) &= ";" & U
            strTmp(4) &= ";" & V

            If (U = clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE) Or (V = clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE) Then
                If (config.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
                    RaiseEvent GetWarning("MESSAGE=No Assignem VentDir perquè no hem trobat dades de la hora " & horaIni & strMsg & "|FUNCIO=CalculaVentDir_Hora", Me)
                End If
                unaHora.VentDir = clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE
                CalculaVentDir = False
            Else

                angle = Math.Atan2(Math.Abs(V), Math.Abs(U)) * 180 / Math.PI
                strTmp(5) &= ";" & angle

                If (U = 0) Then
                    If (V >= 0) Then ventDir = 180
                    If (V < 0) Then ventDir = 0
                Else
                    If (U > 0) And (V > 0) Then ventDir = 270 - angle
                    If (U < 0) And (V < 0) Then ventDir = 90 - angle
                    If (U > 0) And (V < 0) Then ventDir = 270 + angle
                    If (U < 0) And (V > 0) Then ventDir = 90 + angle
                End If

                strTmp(6) &= ";" & angle
                unaHora.VentDir = ventDir
                strTmp(7) &= ";" & angle
                CalculaVentDir = True

            End If

            For j As Integer = 0 To UBound(strTmp)
                strReport &= strTmp(j) & vbCrLf
            Next

        Else
            If (config.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
                RaiseEvent GetWarning("MESSAGE=No Assignem VentDir perquè no hem trobat les variables 33 o 34|FUNCIO=CalculaVentDir_Hora", Me)
            End If
            CalculaVentDir = False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (config.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs = True) Then
            RaiseEvent GetError("MESSAGE=" & ex.Message & ", SOURCE=" & ex.StackTrace & ", FUNCIO=CalculaVentDir_Hora", Me)
        End If
        unaHora.VentDir = clsConfiguracio.NO_DADA_DOUBLE
        CalculaVentDir = False
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: We have no idea which thing is the stringbuilder or if it is even there.  For SB use the methods to concatenate

Comment: @Plutonix sorry the part i changed missed. i updated it

Comment: If you expect that your called methods update your StringBuilder, you need to pass it, now you pass the result of ToString but any change you meke to this string will never update the stringbuilder itself

Comment: @Steve very good point thanks. one more question `sReport &= vbCrLf` can be changed like i did with `sReport.AppendLine()`

Comment: @Steve i didn't know when i pass sReport to function it will change it because they return Boolean! is that how it works? for example here: `oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMax(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport.ToString)`

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do inside those methods. I assume they try to add text to the stringbuilder. (Yes you can replace vbCrLf with and empty call to AppendLine)

Comment: You are forcing us to guess what the called methods do with the passed argument `sReport`.  Either show the code for the methods or describe how the methods use `sReport`.

Comment: @TnTinMn i will update my post to add the function code which is called in class

Comment: @Steve i update the post with a function whichpass the `sReport`

Comment: Again. When you pass the strReport to your _CalculaVentDir_ do not convert it to a string with ToString. Just pass it as strReport. Of course you need to change the parameter received by _CalculaVentDir_ to be a StringBuilder and not a string. Inside _CalculaVentDir_ change the code that uses strReport to work as a StringBuilder (strReport.Append.... and not strReport &=) Now you should see the changes in strReport also in the caller function

Comment: @Steve i changed it, waiting for result ... but the question is when we pass the String to the function he will change Reference `sReport` from the main method who called the function? i can't understand this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMin(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport.ToString)

oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMax(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar, sReport.ToString)
```

... and similar, where you pass `sReport.ToString()` to a method.

You need to change these functions to not even ask for the report. If they need to add something to the report, have them return a string, and then append the result when you call the method:

```
sReport.Appdend(oPuntInterpretar.CalculaTempMin(oConfiguracio, oPuntInterpretar.Dies(i).FranjaMati, oPuntInterpretar.VariablesPG, oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, i - 1, iHoresRestar))
```

You could also change the methods to accept a StringBuilder object instead, but this way is better coding style. The method doesn't really need to know what's already in the report string, and anything more than 3 or 4 arguments to a function is a code smell.

If this report is large, even getting the StringBuilder working may not fix your OutOfMemory problem. If you still have the problem, the next place to look is to use a **`Stream`**, such as a `FileStream`, an ASP.Net `ReponseStream`, or the `Console.Out` stream, all of which you can abstract away via a [`TextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx).

Finally, we can improve on the initial StringBuilder translation:

```
Dim reportBase As String = "ID_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;{0}{1}LATITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;{2}{1}LONGITUD_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;{3}{1}ALCADA_PUNTGEOGRAFIC (metres);{4}{1}TIPUS_PUNTGEOGRAFIC;{5}{1}DIF_HORALOCAL_UTC;{6}{1}DATA_MODEL;{7}{1}DATA_VALIDESA;{8}{1}{1}"

Dim Report As New StringBuilder()
iHoresRestar = dtDataElaboracio.Hour
For Each die In oPuntInterpretar.Dies
    If oConfiguracio.Opcions_Meteo3D.LogPGs Then
        Report.AppendFormat(reportBase, _ 
            oPuntInterpretar.IPuntGeografic,vbCrLf, _ 
             Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Latitud, 2), _
             Math.Round(oPuntInterpretar.Longitud, 2), _
             oPuntInterpretar.Alçada, _
             IIf(oPuntInterpretar.Tipus = clsPuntGeografic.TipusPunt.Poblacio, "POBLACIO", "MUNTANYA"), _
             oPuntInterpretar.DifHoraLocalUTC, _
             dtDataElaboracio.ToString, _
             die.DataValidesa.ToString )
    End If

    '...
```

If you are able to update to a more recent version of Visual Studio (which is **free** now in most cases), we can improve the code further. I'll add Microsoft now specifically *recommends **against*** using Hungarian notation warts on variable names. It's just `report` now, instead of `sReport`, and `puntInterpretar` instead of `oPuntInterpretar`.

Comment: i guess the approach of this application is wrong  have to checking it more it's a huge app

Comment: thanks i changed all the function and methods and it work like a charm now! great thanks to you. i wish i could vote for your answer